# lightning:container is not working in few testing orgs but working fine in others

Tags: lightning-container

lightning:container is not working in few testing orgs but working fine in others. Sometimes it just works after a day or so without me doing any changes. I get the following error, any suggestions on where/what I should be looking.

-- all the critical updates are upto date.

> domain-namespace.container.lightning.com’s server IP address could not
>   be found.

Thanks

Comment: having same issue - how is anyone using lightning container - or are they?